# How to properly mix react-native-gesture-handler touchables with react-native touchables?

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

we're in this situation where we use both `react-native-gesture-handler Touchable`s AND `react-native Touchable`s in our app. (By Touchables I mean TouchableOpacity, TouchableHighlight etc). As you know react-native-gesture-handler provides those components too so that they work when used as a child of a `react-native-gesture-handler` gesture recognizing component.

## Initially

we thought we'd only use `rn-gesture-handler Touchables` in components that absolutely need `rn-gesture-handler Touchables` in order to work (i.e root views wrapped with a [gestureHandlerRootHOC](https://software-mansion.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html#with-wix-react-native-navigation-https-githubcom-wix-react-native-navigation)) and use `rn Touchables` everywhere else.

## Unfortunately

we bumped onto cases where two of those components interfered, and we had weird issues (like touches going through a component as if it had `pointerEvents="none"` just because it used a `rn touchable` and not an `rngh touchable` in Android).

## Possibly

A solution may be to replace EVERY single `rn Touchable` in our app with a `rn-gesture-handler Touchable`, but this is super hard because many of our dependencies are also using `rn Touchables` so it would be hard to replace all that - but also it would be even harder because `rn-gesture-handler Touchables` are [NOT drop in replacements of rn Touchables](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/607) and we've had issues styling `rn-gesture-handler Touchables` indeed.

## Now what?

I need some help with solving that properly - even something hacky like a way to block touches going through react-native touchables would do I think.

Comment: Is this still the case? I feel that this is still an issue?!

Comment: Still the case, yeah..

Comment: k.  I fixed it by making the touch and drag events in the same component level. More flexbox action but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it, first create a `TouchablePlatform.ts` file, then make use of it in your components. When passing `withNativeResponder` as a prop to the component, it will use those from `react-native-gesture-handler`.

```js
// src/commons/components/TouchablePlatform.ts

import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  TouchableNativeFeedbackProps,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableHighlightProps,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  TouchableNativeFeedback as TouchableNativeFeedbackGestureHandler,
  TouchableHighlight as TouchableHighlightGestureHandler,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export type TouchablePlatformProps = {withNativeResponder?: boolean} & (
  | TouchableHighlightProps
  | TouchableNativeFeedbackProps
);

export const TouchablePlatform: FC<TouchablePlatformProps> = ({
  children,
  withNativeResponder = false,
  style = {},
  ...props
}) => {
  if (withNativeResponder) {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      return (
        <TouchableHighlightGestureHandler {...props} style={[{flex: 1}, style]}>
          {children}
        </TouchableHighlightGestureHandler>
      );
    }

    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeedbackGestureHandler
        {...props}
        style={[
          {
            flex: 1,
            maxWidth: '100%',
            width: '100%',
          },
          style,
        ]}>
        {children}
      </TouchableNativeFeedbackGestureHandler>
    );
  }

  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight {...props} style={[{flex: 1}, style]}>
        {children}
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }

  return (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback {...props} style={style}>
      {children}
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
  );
};
```